# Pretty Print objects result in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have dumped results that look like:

```
[
[
    "Account Verification",
    null
],
[
    "Account owner",
    null
],
[
    "Account settings",
    null
],
]
```

and I need to modify syntax in my code so it can look like:

```
{
  "Account owner" : "null",
  "Account settings" : "null",
...
}
```

I need to pretty print with json so it looks different.

My code:

```
$printIt = $this->getExampleRepository()->findAll();

$result = [];

 foreach($printIt as $print){
       $name = $print->getName();
       $value = $print->getValue();

        $result[] = array($name, $value);
    }

    $packIt = json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: and what's your actual question?

Comment: Are you looking for the flag `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` …?

Comment: How to modify my code to print it like in a example I mentioned above. @treyBake

Comment: JSON_FORCE_OBJECT outputs them all in a same row. @04FS

Comment: Probably rather `$result[$name] = $value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = [
    [
        "Account Verification",
        null
    ],
    [
        "Account owner",
        null
    ],
    [
        "Account settings",
        null
    ]
];

$data = array_reduce($data, function($a, $b) {
    $a[$b[0]] = $b[1];
    return $a;
}, []);

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/31072807d16fd060efcec0a18690da279fbd0a27)

Comment: Thanks a lot! @SergioRinaudo

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge,

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    list($name,$value1) = $value;
    // key value pair making and saving to result
    $result[$name] = (!is_null($value1) ? $value1 : "null");
}
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Output**

```
{
    "Account Verification": "null",
    "Account owner": "null",
    "Account settings": "null"
}
```

[**Working demo**.](https://3v4l.org/Ta3OL)

Comment: Thank you. I used answer above, but this code works too. @quickSwap

Comment: Welcome :) Happy coding \m/